# CreateHwndRenderTarget argument list problems

Tags: c++, direct2d

Just started to learn D2D in class and got it all set up with no problems on my laptop. Now I'm trying to get it set up on my desktop at home and I'm running into an issue with creating the Render target.

```
hr = pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, size), &pRT);
```

where

```
ID2D1Factory* pD2DFactory;
ID2D1RenderTarget* pRT;
```

It says that the first argument of CreateHwndRenderTarget should be const, but when I look on the MSDN page they simly just call the function RenderTargetProperties and it works fine for them.

```
Error:  1   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, ID2D1RenderTarget **)
        object type is: ID2D1Factory
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. 
Should have been

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRT;
```

instead of

```
ID2D1RenderTarget* pRT;
```